# What is wrong with this link? when clicked on, browser says "null/"

Tags: null

https://smile.amazon.com/gp/f.html?C=1OR2JD8DH59TD&K=A2CTKC0L6X87GK&R=28ZTBZOJI3VVH&T=C&U=http%3A%2F%2Fnull&A=KQPRJ83ZWZ0RQMDCCLBSZSLUIACA&H=1OLUERCFQKYSOSL3QA4HUYMYKEKA

I am unsure why this link is only coming up as "null/" when entered into browser. Someone please help me fix this!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Anyway, the web server or script may be configured to redirect or forward you to a new url that isn't properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

The link returns a status code 302. The response will have a location attribute in response header which redirects to a second link

https://www.amazon.com/gp/f.html?C=1OR2JD8DH59TD&K=A2CTKC0L6X87GK&R=28ZTBZOJI3VVH&T=C&U=http%3A%2F%2Fnull&A=KQPRJ83ZWZ0RQMDCCLBSZSLUIACA&H=1OLUERCFQKYSOSL3QA4HUYMYKEKA&pldnSite=1

Again the second link returns same status code which redirects to http://null

You can see all this in chrome developer tools under network tab. Make sure 'Preserve log' checkbox is checked else you won't be able to see individual request/responses.

Answer (score 0):

The part

```
http%3A%2F%2Fnull
```

in your link means (after URL decoding)

```
http://null
```

as `%3A` is the hexadecimal presentation of the character `:`, and `%2F` of the character `/`.

This part is preceded with `&U=`; `&` is the parameter's delimiter, `U=` means that the string `http://null` is assigned to the variable `U`.

The code at the server side may do with the content of `U` whatever it wants - it indeed redirects you to its content , i. e. to `http://null`.